# How do I derive the law of supremum of a generic Levy process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum, gaussian-integral, levy-processes

Let ${\bar x} > 0 $, $\sigma >0$, $\mu \in {\mathbb R}$, $T > 0 $ and $\alpha \in {\mathbb R}$.
Let $\phi(x) := \exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi} $ be a probability density of a standard normal variable. Then consider the following integral:

\begin{equation}
F_{\mu\,\sigma}[{\bar x},T]:= \int\limits_T^\infty \frac{1}{\xi^\alpha} \cdot \phi\left(\frac{{\bar x} - \mu \xi}{\sigma \sqrt{\xi}}\right) d\xi
\end{equation}

This integral appears in the context of either  the first hitting time of a barrier  by a Brownian motion or of the law of the supremum of the Brownian motion (see Theorem 46.4 page 348 in

*Sato, Ken-Iti*, Lévy processes and infinitely divisible distributions, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics. 68. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xii, 486 p. (1999). [ZBL0973.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0973.60001).).

We have calculated this integral for $\alpha = 3/2 + m$ where $ m\in {\mathbb Z}$. The result reads:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left.
F_{\mu\,\sigma}[{\bar x},T]:=
\frac{e^{\frac{\mu {\bar x}}{\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2}}
(-1)^m
\frac{d^{|m|}}{d \theta^{|m|}}
\right\{
\begin{array}{lll}
%
\left.
\frac{e^{-2 \sqrt{\theta b}}}{\sqrt{\theta}}
-
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\theta}}
\left(
e^{+2\sqrt{\theta b}} erfc[\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\sqrt{T}} + \sqrt{b T}]
+
e^{-2\sqrt{\theta b}} erfc[\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\sqrt{T}} - \sqrt{b T}]
\right) \right|_{\theta = a} & \mbox{if $m \ge 0 $} \\
%
\left.
\frac{e^{-2 \sqrt{a \theta}}}{\sqrt{a}}
-
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a}}
\left(
e^{+2\sqrt{a \theta}} erfc[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{T}} + \sqrt{\theta T}]
+
e^{-2\sqrt{a \theta}} erfc[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{T}} - \sqrt{\theta T}]
\right)  \right|_{\theta=b}& \mbox{if $m <0 $}
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
where $(a,b) = ({\bar x}^2/(2 \sigma^2),\mu^2/(2 \sigma^2)) $.

The derivation is not complicated. It basically boils down to using [this result](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7#E7) and then differentiating with respect to parameters of the integrand to induce an arbitrary power function in that integrand. Below is a verification of that result in Mathematica:

```
In[7307]:= phi[x_] := Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi];

sig = RandomReal[{1, 2}];
{mu} = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 1];
{T, x} = RandomReal[{1, 3}, 2];
m = RandomInteger[{0, 10}];
xi =.;
NIntegrate[
 1/xi^((3 + 2 m)/2) phi[(x - mu xi)/(sig Sqrt[xi])], {xi, T, Infinity}]
Exp[(mu x)/sig^2]/Sqrt[2 Pi] NIntegrate[
  1/xi^((3 + 2 m)/2) Exp[-(x^2/(2 sig^2 xi)) - (mu^2 xi)/(
     2 sig^2)], {xi, T, Infinity}]
{a, b} = {x^2/(2 sig^2), (mu^2) /(2 sig^2)};
Exp[(mu x)/sig^2]/Sqrt[2 Pi] (2) NIntegrate[
  xi^(2 m) Exp[-a xi^2 - b/xi^2], {xi, 0, 1/Sqrt[T]}]
th =.;
Exp[(mu x)/sig^2]/
  Sqrt[2] (D[
    1/Sqrt[th] Exp[-2 Sqrt[th b]] - 
     1/(2 Sqrt[
       th]) (Exp[2 Sqrt[th b]] Erfc[Sqrt[th]/Sqrt[T] + Sqrt[b T]] + 
        Exp[-2 Sqrt[ th b]] Erfc[Sqrt[th]/Sqrt[T] - Sqrt[b T]]), {th, 
     m}] /. th :> a) (-1)^m

m = -m;
NIntegrate[
 1/xi^((3 + 2 m)/2) phi[(x - mu xi)/(sig Sqrt[xi])], {xi, T, Infinity}]
Exp[(mu x)/sig^2]/
  Sqrt[2] (D[
    1/Sqrt[a] Exp[-2 Sqrt[a th]] - 
     1/(2 Sqrt[
       a]) (Exp[2 Sqrt[a th]] Erfc[Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[T] + Sqrt[th T]] + 
        Exp[-2 Sqrt[ a th]] Erfc[
          Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[T] - Sqrt[th T]]), {th, -m}] /. th :> b) (-1)^m
  

Out[7313]= 0.000155233

Out[7314]= 0.000155233

Out[7316]= 0.000155233

Out[7318]= 0.000155233

Out[7320]= 70253.1

Out[7321]= 70253.1
```

My question would be twofold, firstly how does the result look like when the parameter $\alpha$ is arbitrary? The second question would be more generic. Note that the function $\phi()$ is nothing else but the probability density of a Brownian motion at time one, i.e. $\phi(x) := \phi_{B_1}(x) $. Would it be possible to derive the result if we were to replace the Brownian motion by some other Levy process, for example a Levy stable process or a jump diffusion ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer to the first question. Take $\alpha > 1$ and $a,b \ge 0$. Then the following identities hold true:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&I^{(\alpha)}_{a,b}(T):= \int\limits_0^T e^{- \frac{a}{\xi^\alpha} - b \xi^\alpha } d\xi = \tag{1} \\
&&e^{-\sqrt{4 a b}} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\alpha}\int\limits_0^{T^\alpha}
u^{-1+\frac{1}{\alpha}}  \cdot \phi(\frac{\sqrt{2 a} - \sqrt{2 b} u}{\sqrt{u}}) du = \tag{2} \\
&&\underline{\int\limits_0^a \frac{1}{\alpha} (a-s)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Gamma[-\frac{1}{\alpha},(a-s) T^{-\alpha}] \sqrt{b} \frac{I_1(2 \sqrt{b s})}{\sqrt{s}} ds}+\\
&&\int\limits_0^b \frac{1}{\alpha} (b-s)^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}} \gamma[+\frac{1}{\alpha},(b-s) T^{\alpha}] \sqrt{a} \frac{I_1(2 \sqrt{a s})}{\sqrt{s}} ds + \\
&&-\underline{\underline{T I_0(2 \sqrt{a b})}} + \underline{\frac{1}{\alpha} a^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \Gamma(-\frac{1}{\alpha},a T^{-\alpha})} + \frac{1}{\alpha} b^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}} \gamma(+\frac{1}{\alpha},b T^{\alpha}) \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

In $(2)$ we substituted for $u=\xi^\alpha$. In $(3)$ we did the following. We differentiated the original quantity with respect to parameters and established that $d^2/(da db) I^{(\alpha)}_{a,b}(T) = I^{(\alpha)}_{a,b}(T) $ subject to $I^{(\alpha)}_{0,b} = 1/\alpha b^{-1/\alpha}  \gamma(1/\alpha, b T^\alpha) $ and $I^{(\alpha)}_{a,0} = 1/\alpha a^{+1/\alpha}  \Gamma(-1/\alpha, a T^{-\alpha}) $. Then we used [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524641/about-the-linear-pde-u-x-1x-2x-3-x-n-u) which we integrated by parts once.

```
In[2575]:= {a, b, alpha, T} = RandomReal[{2, 5}, 4]; z =.;
NIntegrate[Exp[-a/xi^alpha - b xi^alpha], {xi, 0, T}]
Exp[-Sqrt[4 a b]] Sqrt[2 Pi]/alpha NIntegrate[
  phi[(Sqrt[2 a] - Sqrt[2 b] u)/Sqrt[u]] u^(-1 + 1/alpha), {u, 0, 
   T^(alpha)}]
ff[a_] := (-alpha E^(-a T^-alpha) T + 
  a^(1/alpha) Gamma[-(1/alpha), a T^-alpha])/(
 a alpha^2);(*D[1/alpha a^(1/alpha) Gamma[-1/alpha,a T^(-alpha)],a]*)


gg[b_] := (
 alpha E^(-b T^alpha) T - b^(-1/alpha) Gamma[1/alpha, 0, b T^alpha])/(
 alpha^2 b);
(*D[1/alpha b^(-1/alpha) Gamma[1/alpha,0,b T^(alpha)],b]*)
NIntegrate[ (ff[s]) BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[b (a - s)]], {s, 0, a}] + 
 NIntegrate[ (gg[s]) BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[a (b - s)]], {s, 0, b}] + 
 T BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[b (a)]]

NIntegrate[
  1/alpha (a - s)^(1/alpha) Gamma[-1/alpha, (a - s) T^(-alpha)] (
   b BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[b s]])/Sqrt[b s], {s, 0, a}] + 
 NIntegrate[
  1/alpha (b - s)^(-1/alpha) Gamma[1/alpha, 0, (b - s) T^(alpha)] (
   a BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[a s]])/Sqrt[a s], {s, 0, b}] + -T BesselI[0, 
   2 Sqrt[b (a)]] +
 1/alpha a^(1/alpha) Gamma[-1/alpha, a T^(-alpha)] + 
 1/alpha b^(-1/alpha) Gamma[1/alpha, 0, b T^(alpha)]

Out[2576]= 0.00025449

Out[2577]= 0.00025449

Out[2579]= 0.000254489 + 1.0681*10^-11 I

Out[2580]= 0.00025449 + 3.83412*10^-16 I
```

Unfortunately my present knowledge about Bessel functions is insufficient to be able to complete this calculation.

###### Update:

By taking the limit of $T \rightarrow \infty $ in the above we get two interesting identities:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&I^{(\alpha)}_{a,b}(\infty) = \\
&& \frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\alpha} \int\limits_0^a (a-s)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \sqrt{b} \frac{I_1(2 \sqrt{b s})}{\sqrt{s}} ds+\\
&& \frac{\Gamma(+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\alpha} \int\limits_0^b (b-s)^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}} \sqrt{a} \frac{I_1(2 \sqrt{a s})}{\sqrt{s}} ds+\\
&&\frac{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\alpha} a^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} +
\frac{\Gamma(+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\alpha} b^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}  = \\
&&
\frac{\pi  b^{-1/\alpha } \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{\alpha }\right) \left(\,
   _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha };a b\right)-a^{\frac{1}{\alpha }} b^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}
   \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;1+\frac{1}{\alpha };a b\right)\right)}{\alpha }
\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{b} \int\limits_0^a \frac{I_1(2 \sqrt{b s})}{\sqrt{s}} ds - I_0(2 \sqrt{ a b}) + 1 \equiv 0
\end{equation}

```
In[2768]:= {a, b} = RandomReal[{1, 2}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
NIntegrate[Sqrt[b] BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[b s]]/Sqrt[s], {s, 0, a}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15] - BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[a b]] + 1
 (-1 + Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, a b]) - 
 BesselI[0, 2 Sqrt[a b]] + 1

{a, b, alpha} = RandomReal[{2, 5}, 3]; z =.;
NIntegrate[Exp[-a/xi^alpha - b xi^alpha], {xi, 0, Infinity}]

Gamma[-1/alpha]/
   alpha NIntegrate[ (a - s)^(1/alpha) (b BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[b s]])/
    Sqrt[b s], {s, 0, a}] + 
 Gamma[+1/alpha]/
   alpha NIntegrate[ (b - s)^(-1/alpha) (a BesselI[1, 2 Sqrt[a s]])/
    Sqrt[a s], {s, 0, b}] +
 Gamma[-1/alpha]/alpha a^(1/alpha) + Gamma[+1/alpha]/alpha b^(-1/alpha)

Gamma[-1/alpha]/
   alpha ((1/alpha)! b a^(1 + 1/alpha) ((a b)^(-1 - 1/(2 alpha))
        BesselI[1/alpha, 2 Sqrt[a b]] - 1/(
      a b Gamma[(1 + 2 alpha)/alpha]) - 1/(
      a b alpha Gamma[(1 + 2 alpha)/alpha]))) +
 Gamma[+1/alpha]/
   alpha ((-1/alpha)! a b^(1 - 1/alpha) ((a b)^(-1 + 1/(2 alpha))
        BesselI[-1/alpha, 2 Sqrt[a b]] - 1/(
      a b Gamma[(1 - 2 alpha)/-alpha]) + 1/(
      a b alpha Gamma[(1 - 2 alpha)/-alpha]))) +
 Gamma[-1/alpha]/alpha a^(1/alpha) + Gamma[+1/alpha]/alpha b^(-1/alpha)

(b^(-1/alpha) \[Pi] Csc[\[Pi]/
  alpha] (-a^((1/alpha)) b^(1/alpha)
     Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1 + 1/alpha, a b] + 
   Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[(-1 + alpha)/alpha, a b]))/alpha


Out[2769]= 0.*10^-15

Out[2770]= 0.*10^-49

Out[2772]= 0.0000946722

Out[2773]= 0.0000946621

Out[2774]= 0.0000946722

Out[2775]= 0.0000946722
```